# Unpacking data-attribuetes from object in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with problem where I pass object to a jQuery dialog and then can't get access to this object although object is passed correctly.

I need to get values from data-attributes.

This is my code:

```
    $('.hyper').click(function (event) {

        $('#button-e').data(
            'data', this
        ).dialog('open');
    });

                $("#button-e").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 350,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                'Ok': function(){

                    var myObj= $(this).data('data');

                    console.log(myObj);

                },

            },
            close: function () {}
    });
```

This is what shows up in console from "console.log(myObj)"

```
<td id="button-e" data-attr1="2" data-attr2="3" data-attr3="2011.74">test</td>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample? that has library, so we can run and check.

Answer (score 0):

You can access data attributes like this -

```
var myObjData1= $(this).data('attr1');
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this does not work. An undefinded object appears in the console